# How to check if two words are next to each other in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a function to test if two words are near or not in a string but I keep getting *"They are far"* for both tests, so each case is `None`.

```
import re

nearby_words = ['daisy', 'martha']

def check_nearness(text):
    word1 = nearby_words[0]
    word2 = nearby_words[1]
    pattern = re.compile("\b(?:"+word1+"\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,5}?"+word2+"|"+word2+"\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,5}?"+word1+")\b")
    if re.match(pattern,text) is not None:
        print('they are near')
    else:
        print('they are far')


check_nearness("daisy is near martha")

check_nearness("daisy is in this case more than five words from martha")
```

Comment: How are you defining nearness? Have you thought about using edit distance / Levenshtein distance?

Comment: It seems like the OP is interested in the literal number of words (or characters) that separates the two words of interest...am I wrong in this assumption? If you are interested in the similarity of two words than Levenshtein distance would be a good starting topic to look into (as well as the fuzzywuzzy Python library)

Comment: Your regex string is incorrect, you should use single quotes and `r`. Try `r'\b(?:'+word1+r'\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,5}?'+word2+r'|'+word2+r'\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,5}?'+word1+r')\b'`

Comment: @pault sorry for being vague, rahlf23 is correct, I mean the number of words between two words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this regex a try:

```
(?:\bdaisy\b(?: +[^ \n]*){0,5} *\bmartha\b)|(?:\bmartha\b(?: +[^ \n]*){0,5} *\bdaisy\b)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iLIeGy/3/)**

This regex will work for both the cases:

- When `martha` comes before `daisy`
- When `daisy` comes before `martha`

**Explanation**

- `(?:\bdaisy\b(?: +[^ \n]*){0,5} *\bmartha\b)`

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `daisy` - matches `daisy`
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?: +[^ \n]*){0,5}` - matches 0 to 5 occurrences of spaces followed by characters that is not a space or a newline
  - `*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a space
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `martha` - matches `martha`
  - `\b` - a word boundary
- `|` - OR
- `(?:\bmartha\b(?: +[^ \n]*){0,5} *\bdaisy\b)` - similar to the one explained above. Just swapped `martha` and `daisy`.